Old Contributions Show as Made Through New Page
We created a new test contribution page, with ID 4, and now several contributions from years ago are showing up as having been made through the new page, which is impossible.
My guess is that there was previously a contribution page with ID 4 that was deleted, and that this ID remained in the old contributions.  Is this possible, ie could a page have been deleted and the ID remain in in the contributions?
Is there any way of checking?

The ID in these tables would normally be an auto-increment- so unless someone deliberately reset that in the db, the outcome you describe would not be expected.
If you have logging on and access to the DB then you can look in log_civicrm_contribution_page to see the history of addition/deletion/changes to the pages

Thank you; yes, that's what I would have expected. Not sure if I have access to the DB but I can pursue that with the developer. I have come new to it.
